# Is "you will hurt" correct?

Tags: difference, verbs, passive-voice, active-voice, quotations

Is it correct to say 'you will hurt' or 'you will get hurt'? I read this quote on the net:

> “It’s not a question of whether you will hurt, or of how much you will hurt; it’s a question of what you will do, and how well you will do it, while pain has her wanton way with you.”
>
> ― Daniel James Brown, *The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics*

And another thing - the **her** in the last line it's meant a person or otherwise it should be 'pain has **his** wanton'.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, but it's atypical phrasing in order to emphasize that the pain *will happen*, and when it does, it will happen to *them, personally*.  This makes it a kind of *threat*, but also a *challenge*.

The more common phrasing would be:

> It’s not a question of whether **it will hurt**, or of how much **it will hurt** ...

As Jason Bassford's comment mentions, "her" is a feminine personification of the general concept of pain, which otherwise would be gender-neutral.  There is often a difference in nuance between calling something "he" vs. "she" -- but since this is mostly personal interpretation (and hardly specific to English) I leave it to you to imagine why the coach characterizes pain as *female*.